# Convert rows into columns dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Need help to convert table rows into columns dynamically based on the data in C#.

[image]

Expected result as follows,

```
          Attribute                 10 min              20 min      30 min
          Component A Test           5                  8            10
          Component B Test           6                  9            11
          Component C Test           7                  9            12

          Attribute      Right #    Left #
          Component A       5J      7C
          Component B       6J      8C

          Component X   ZZJ
          Component Y   ZZK
```

Comment: SQL PIVOT/UNPIVOT is your best bet, nothing to do with C# though...https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f0b2ed/pivot-and-unpovit-in-sql-server/

Comment: Looks like you'll need to split your column `Attribute` as well, as it's storing more than 1 piece of information. Ideally you should be normalising your data.

Comment: I'm trying not to use PIVOT and UNPIVOT, would like to add additional columns to do the task in C#.

Answer (score 1):

TypeBuilder , FieldBuilder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder?view=netframework-4.8   will help you create class and then its objects whose property you can define at run time. It may take a while to understand it but it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split string and check partial value so your code will not be reusable
If you get time column separately that will be much simpler. You can sum up results if need be.

```
 public class Row
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Attribute { get; set; } 
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }


    public class Col
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Attribute { get; set; } 
        public int _10_Mins { get; set; } 
        public int _20_Mins { get; set; } 
        public int _30_Mins { get; set; } 
    }

    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Row> rows = new List<Row>(); 

            List<Col> list = rows.Select(r => new Col()
            {
               Id = r.Id,
               Attribute = r.Attribute.Split('@')[0],
                 _10_Mins = rows.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Attribute == r.Attribute && c.Attribute.EndsWith("10 min")).Value,
                 _20_Mins = rows.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Attribute == r.Attribute && c.Attribute.EndsWith("20 min")).Value,
                 _30_Mins = rows.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Attribute == r.Attribute && c.Attribute.EndsWith("30 min")).Value, 
            }).ToList();  
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your valuable inputs, added time header but it still shows multiple records. updated your code.